Are non HEPA filters a hazard for allergic patients?
I've learned most robot vacuum cleaners don't have true HEPA filters, but the so called high efficiency filters.
Do you know if these filters are safe to use for allergic people?

The pros and cons of different types of vacuums and filters aren't on topic here. You can see a list of questions appropriate for this site by visiting the [help] and reading what topics can I ask about here?.

I’m voting to close this question because it's not about medical sciences as defined in the [help].

Thanks @Carey Gregory. I wasn't sure where to post it and asked at Meta. I was suggested to post it here. :/

Also, thanks for pointing at the help center. I have edited the question in an attempt to make it more direct and appropiate in this community.

"Safe for allergic people" is very dependent on your definition of "safe". They're "safe"; whether they will improve your allergic symptoms or make them worse is another matter. Did you search the literature at all?

Thank you for your input @anongoodnurse. Sorry, I think that my latest editing of the question left it too short. I will make it clearer later today. In the meanwhile: Yes, I spent a couple of days searching on the net and also at a scientific database. I found interesting info and specific papers with the term HEPA (but any related to the non true HEPA filters, though). With the word 'safe' I mean that the allergic particles are retained inside the filter and allergic people can confidently use it as in HEPA to clean their house.

@Andres - Then the answer is "no". Searching the allergy literature helps. Robot vacuums stir up and expel fine particles. If you're allergic to larger particles, maybe useful if it vacuums while you're away and leave time for what it missed to settle. A good allergist will help you to mitigate symptoms; the average allergist will just shrug and medicate. Your best outcome really depends on your level of expertise and your ability to advocate for yourself. Learn to love Google Scholar. Good luck!

Thank you @anongoodnurse, your suggestion is exactly the only solution that came to my mind: leaving home while the robot is cleaning and come back in a while. I read dust particles take to settle down from 20 min to 3 hours. Good point about the "average allergist" comment. I'm a bit fed up with just reducing the medical problems to taking pills without considering the whole picture of every person. I will try the robot and will come back here to tell my experience.
